# Regex expression to find URLs ending with arbitrary string and not a certain symbol

Tags: regex, google-analytics

Let's say I have URLs of the form:

/path1/path2/path3

or

/path1/path2

And I want to grab all URLs containing any /path1/path2 but *not* that also have another slash, as they will if they also have a /path3.

So, a statement like: /path1/.* to find all /path1/ with any string in the path2 position, but then exclude anything that also has another slash, so that I am getting all /path1/path2 possibilities but excluding all that are /path1/path2/path3

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this: `^\/[\w]+\/[\w]+$`

- start from beginning of string: ^
- look for / followed by one or more alphanumeric
- look for another / followed by one or more alphanumeric
- and this should be the end of the pattern: $

also note that I have used \ as escape sequence.

[see example here](https://regex101.com/r/uRdMiD/6/)